# Can I save a Dictionary of interfaces or the inherited classes and then call Create on the sub-classes from that dictionary?

Tags: delphi, inheritance, interface, parent-child, pascal

What I want to do is have a dictionary of different class types that all implement an interface or have a shared parent class. Using this list, I want to instantiate the correct one from a string identifying the one I want.

So if the list is classes "b", "c", and "d", who all inherit from "a" OR who all implement an interface "a", I want to load those types into a list with the class names as identifiers and then Create whichever class matches the string from the list.

In the b, c and d classes I am adding it to the dictionary as part of the initialization section.

The ultimate goal of this is to have database driven customization.

I first tried to use an interface that all classes implement and have a dictionary<string, Interface>. I couldn't seem to include the constructor as part of the interface, so I moved on to another idea.

I tried to have all my classes inherit a base class with some abstract functions/procedures I'll use. I make the dictionary<string, TBaseClass> But when I try to add one of my subclasses to it, it gives me e2010 incompatible types.

Answer (score 3):

If all the classes have a common base class, you can store their meta class types in the dictionary and then construct them when needed, eg:

```
type
  TBaseClass = class
  public
    constructor Create; virtual;
    ...
  end;
  TClassOfBase = class of TBaseClass;

... 

var
  Dict: TDictionary<string, TClassOfBase>;
```

```
type
  TClassB = class(TBaseClass)
    ...
  end;

...

Dict.Add('b', TClassB);
```

```
var
  obj: TBaseClass;

obj := Dict['desiredType'].Create;
...
obj.Free;
```

If all the classes have a common interface instead, you can store factory functions in the dictionary and then call them when needed, eg:

```
type
  IMyInterface = interface
    ...
  end;

... 

var
  Dict: TDictionary<string, TFunc<IMyInterface>>;
```

```
type
  TClassB = class(TInterfaceObject, IMyInterface)
    ...
  end;

...

Dict.Add('b',
  function: IMyInterface;
  begin
    Result := TClassB.Create;
  end
);
```

```
var
  intf: IMyInterface;

intf := Dict['desiredType']();
...
```